# Using .Select to get single item from sub list, then assigning individual properties of that item to view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have pretty much solved this problem but I am wondering whether there is a more efficient way of doing this using Entity framework / SQL.

Essentially, what i am doing is performing a subquery to get a SINGLE item on a list of objects that are connected to a parent entity. I then want to extract only a few columns from that single entity.

The first way, which doesn't work but shows my possible thought process was to put each object into a temporary variable and then create the view:

```
        _context.IcoInfos.Select((i) =>
        {
            var reward = i.SocialRewards.OrderByDescending(s => s.EndDate).FirstOrDefault();
            return new IcoInfoRewardCountViewModel()
            {
                CampaignName = i.Name,
                CurParticipants = reward.CurParticipants,
                Title = reward.CustomTitle,
                IsLive = reward.IsLive
            };
        });
```

The second way, which works, I am creating a temporary model which stores the single database row of the sublist result...

```
        _context.IcoInfos.Select((i) => new
        {
            Reward = i.SocialRewards.OrderByDescending(s => s.EndDate).FirstOrDefault(),
            IcoName = i.Name
        }).Select(t => new IcoInfoRewardCountViewModel()
        {
            CampaignName = t.IcoName,
            CurParticipants = t.Reward.CurParticipants,
            Title = t.Reward.CustomTitle, 
            IsLive = t.Reward.IsLive                
        }).ToList();
```

My question is, is this second way the only/best way to achieve this?

Comment: The second way is very much better in terms of performance. Better still try do a unit testing on both methods

Comment: FirstOrDefault can return default value (usually is null) and in the next line you get that result and access it's properties, so you can have a NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is ok but for bigger application will cause you trouble if application growth larger and you have a lot information to store in the model.

So I think you can use automapper to make your code more clean.

Example

To use autoampper I need to define a model class and DTO class that share some same properties.

```
public class Comment
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment ParentComment { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public virtual User? User { get; set; }
    public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; set; }
}

public class CommentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqeId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Comment ParentComment { get; set; }
    public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

I also need to define the profile class to register mapping

```
public class CommentProfile : Profile
{
    public CommentProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Comment, CommentDto>(MemberList.None).ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Then I will need to register into DI container in startup.cs

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

Then I can use like this

```
var comments = await _unitOfWork.Repository<Comment>().Query()
                .Include(x => x.User)
                .Include(c => c.Post)
                .Select(x => new CommentViewModel
                {
                    Comment = _mapper.Map<Comment, CommentDto>(x),
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

It will make the code more clear and I dont have to do manual mapping